# Strip off any characters from a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a stored procedures which will give the next value on the row.

In my case, I'm sending a reference number and the stored procedure returns the next ref number using `MIN` and `>`. However the ref number in the table includes characters like 123GF, 256ER, 25GD which gives me an error when converting `Varchar` to `int`.

How would I strip off any non-numerical number before comparing the value with my passing value?

This is my current procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].nextprevious
    @refId INTEGER,
    @Next Bit
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    DECLARE @lReturn    INTEGER

    IF(@Next = 1)
  SELECT REF
  FROM TABLE
  WHERE REF =( select MIN(REF)
     FROM TABLE  WHERE REF > @refId)     
     else
       SELECT REF
  FROM TABLE
  WHERE REF =( select MAX(REF)
     FROM [REF    WHERE REF < @refId)

      SELECT @lReturn = @@ROWCOUNT
          RETURN @lReturn       
END
GO
```

Comment: Are you aware of the `lead()` function? That will give you a value of the "next row".

Comment: are the numeric values always first in the column ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQLServer, do like below

[image]

Other Solution is using Replace Function:

```
select replace(Ref,'A','') from table --to cut off one char
select replace(replace(Ref,'A',''),'B','') from table --to cut off A and B char
```

Likewise do for your chars

Comment: I don't understand this. Where should I put this? What is "Stuff"?

Comment: While passing the value to the SP, do the above. Stuff is the inbuilt function in SQLServer.

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots. Post SQL statements as (properly formatted) text.

Comment: I tried posting, but it throws error. I tried formatting but it still fails, so for time being posted as screenshot

Comment: I needed to strip of the characters from the value being compare from the table. In my case, its "REF".

Answer (score 0):

Create a computed column in the table, use that column for comparison instead:

```
ALTER table [tablename] ADD ref_int 
  as CAST(LEFT(REF, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REF + 'x') - 1) AS INT) PERSISTED
```

Comment: What if ? IF Ref column has value something like this 123GF456LF

Comment: @knkarthick24 to ensure that was not a posibility. I asked before posting

Comment: I totally agree with you that. I just want to know whether any other simple way to achieve the same if numbers spread across the string,so asked.

Comment: @knkarthick24 you could use nested replace statements, that is the best way i can think off right now

Comment: @t-clausen.dk The database contents very sensitive information hence I can't add or edit the table in any way. Is it not possible to do it while reading it?

Comment: @YagneshCangi this statement will not mess with any data. This is the right way of handling your issue, there is absolutely no other good way, short of reworking your table. This is why you should always store the columns in the right type. If your data is this sensitive, you could consider changing your table so you are using the correct types instead